# What data should we sign in a transaction of cryptocurrency?

Tags: transactions, cryptography, cryptocurrency, wallet

I am working on some cryptography about cryptocurrency I have two problem about cold wallet and transactions
I think I have guessed the answer these days, please see if it is the case

Q1. How to allocate a transaction fee to miners ?

The following is my original guess

Situation: Alice wants to send to Bob $100 with $5 transaction fee

step 1. create transaction request: To BobAddr $100, fee $5

step 2. A full node miner1 picks up this request and make a raw transaction then send back to Alice

```
    ______________________________________________                             
    | rawTx                                       | 
    | [Input1 $105]   [output1 to BobAddr   $100] |  
    |                 [output2 to miner1Addr $ 5] |          
    |_____________________________________________|
```

step 3. Alice signs this well-formed raw transaction

```
    _______________________________________________________   
    | signedTx                                             |   
    | [AliceSig Input1 $105]   [output1 to BobAddr   $100] |    
    |                          [output2 to miner1Addr $ 5] |   
    |______________________________________________________|
```

step 4. Broadcast this signed transaction, and this tx may be included into a block by miners

But this situation has a problem, if this transaction is successfully mined by miner2 or miner3
, how could they earn this $5 tx fee, because the [output2 to miner1Addr $ 5] is already be signed by Alice
and can not be tampered

According to my understanding, is the solution as follows:

step 1. create transaction request: To recvAddr $100, fee $5

step 2. A full node miner1 picks up this request and make a raw transaction then send back to Alice

```
    ______________________________________________   
    | rawTx                                       |  
    | [Input1 $105]   [output1 to BobAddr   $100] |             
    |_____________________________________________|
```

step 3. Alice signs this well-formed raw transaction

```
    _______________________________________________________  
    | signedTx                                             |  
    | [AliceSig Input1 $105]   [output1 to BobAddr   $100] | 
    | _____________________________________________________|
```

step 4. Broadcast this signed transaction, and this tx may be included into a block by miners

In this situation, no matter which miner successfully mine a new block,
He just adds up the difference between input and output of every tx and generates his own output.

If Eve mined a block, and this block contains 3 transaction

```
  ____________________________________________________________________  
  |   Block                                                          |    
  | _________________________________________________________________|    
  |                                                                  |   
  |  _______________________________________________________         | 
  |  | signedTx1                                            |        | 
  |  | [AliceSig Input1 $105]   [output1 to BobAddr   $100] |        | 
  |  |______________________________________________________|        | 
  |  ___________________________________________________________     |  
  |  | signedTx2                                                |    |   
  |  | [JohnSig Input1 $1024]   [output1 to JeromeAddr   $1296] |    |   
  |  | [JohnSig Input2 $ 384]   [output2 to changeAddr   $  12] |    |   
  |  |__________________________________________________________|    | 
  |  ___________________________________________________________     |  
  |  | signedTx3                                                |    |  
  |  | [OscarSig     Input1 $20]   [output1 to TimoAddr  $80]   |    |  
  |  | [SvietlanaSig Input2 $30]                                |    |  
  |  | [MarioSig     Input3 $40]                                |    |  
  |  |__________________________________________________________|    |  
  |__________________________________________________________________|
```

Eve just calculate the tx fee: $5 + $100 + $10 = $115,
and create a UTXO for herself
[src tx??? to EveAddr  $115] without signing by any one.

Is this guess close to the truth?

Q2. A company want to develop a wallet software for many cryptocurrency include XXXcoin.
But XXXcoin is not an open source project, the company don't know the data structure of tx of XXXcoin.
Can this wallet sign transaction of XXXcoin?

Thank you

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thank you for watching my questions, I have re-edited the question. Is my guess close to the facts?